# Why do I get a null character when I read a second line with fscanf?

Tags: c

I am trying to read first line of the file completely until `\n` and store it in a variable. Then I try to read the 2nd line of the file, but it's not giving the correct output. I am not sure what is happening. Is it reading a blank, or maybe is the file pointer moving after fscanf()?

abc.txt file contains :

```
>hello test file<br>
1
```

But the output (what I get in printf) is:

```
status:
>pwd :hello test file
```

So why is status missing here?

Here is my program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char status,pwd[30];
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("abc.txt","r");
  if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file ");
        fclose(fp);
       return 0;
    }

  fscanf(fp,"%29[^\n]",pwd);  
  fscanf(fp,"%c",&status);

  fclose(fp);
  printf("\n Status : %c pwd: %s",status,pwd);
}
```

Comment: put `fgetc(fp);` between last two fscanf(), hope that will solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

here:

```
 fscanf(fp,"%29[^\n]",pwd);
```

You're telling `fscanf()` to read up until it sees a newline, then to stop. Here:

```
 fscanf(fp,"%c",&status);
```

You're telling `fscanf()` to read the next character (which is the newline). Then here:

```
printf("\n Status : %c pwd: %s",status,pwd);
```

It prints the newline as a character (so you can't see it, it's just a blank line)

You need to consume that newline if you want to read it like this with fscanf().

One option would be to just do something like:

```
fscanf(fp,"%29[^\n]",pwd); 
fgetc(fp);
fscanf(fp,"%c",&status);
```

Another resolution would be to add a space before the `%c` to tell `fscanf()` to ignore white space characters:

```
fscanf(fp,"%29[^\n]",pwd); 
fscanf(fp," %c",&status);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `fscanf` is putting the newline back, and so the second `fscanf` is just reading the newline, not the character you want. You can get around this by putting a space before the `%c`, e.g.

```
fscanf(fp," %c",&status);
```